# How do i install a service using InstallUtil.exe on Inno Setup?

Tags: service, inno-setup

I know that there is a question similar to mine that has been answered, but unfortunately, that solution didn't work for me.

I am trying to install a background service for an application. 
But I get the error message -
 "Cannot start service from the command line or a debugger. A Windows Service must be installed (using installutil.exe) and then started with the server explorer, Windows Service Administrative tool or the NET START command."

The code I have so far is a mash-up of two answers I found so far, but neither work. 
This is my current code:

```
[run]                                         
Filename: "{app}\LBCPUMon.exe"; Parameters: "--install"; Flags: runhidden
Filename: "{app}\LBCPUMon.exe"; Parameters:  "create LBCPUMon start= auto binPath= ""{app}\LBCPUMon.exe""" ; Flags: runhidden

[UninstallRun]
Filename: {app}\LBCPUMon.exe; Parameters: "--uninstall" ; Flags: runhidden
Filename: {app}\LBCPUMon.exe; Parameters: "stop LBCPUMon" ; Flags: runhidden
Filename: {app}\LBCPUMon.exe; Parameters: "delete LBCPUMon" ; Flags: runhidden
```

Thank you.

Comment: *"didn't work for me"* didn't work for us as a problem description.

Comment: Do not [spam other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50684584/850848). Formulate your problem!

Comment: https://paste.ee/p/vWN05

Comment: Thank you Joshua, I am trying that now.

Comment: Hello @Joshua,  Sorry for the late response. I tried the code you added but I still have the same error message appear.  Do you think its the codes problem or could be another issue?

Comment: @Ollie well are you sure that LBCPUMon.exe is a service?

Comment: @Ollie can you share LBCPUMon.exe?

Comment: @Joshua I can share it with you yes, what is the best way to do this?